# jQuery-lightbox plugin conflict with jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, lightbox

I am working using jqgrid and lightbox plugin.

```
    <%-- These are the javascripts conflicts each other --%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="LightBox/JS/prototype.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I replace the these file with each other then jqgrid working fine but lightbox not work, and vice verse.
Please help me in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution by exploring:
When two libraries conflict the official solution is to resolve conflict by calling:

```
   var k = jQuery.noConflict();
   // Code
```

you can find solution from bellow link:
[prototype confilct with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714844/jquery-prototype-conflict-alternative-solutions)